# Will the same type of Pokemon always appear in the same spawn location?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a new app for iOS/browsers (soon for Android) called www.pokemonradargo.com. Users can add locations for *specific* Pokemon they saw or caught. But I doubt the usefulness of such an app. **Will a specific Pokemon actually repeat their spawn location in Pokemon Go?**

This post about spawns does not answer this: [How do I find Pokémon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272561/how-do-i-find-pok%C3%A9mon)

This one: [How long until a pokemon respawns in the same spot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274987/how-long-until-a-pokemon-respawns-in-the-same-spot), is about *different* Pokemon spawning in the same spot, not the *same* Pokemon each time.

Comment: I believe this question would answer what you're looking for: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274987/how-long-until-a-pokemon-respawns-in-the-same-spot

Comment: That question talks about pokemon spawns but not exactly the same pokemon.

Comment: lois6b: While we can answer questions about the game itself, we can't really answer questions about third-party applications. While Pokemon Radar is obviously related to Pokemon Go, it is an unofficial application that we cannot vouch for, so it doesn't fall within the scope of this site.

Comment: I know, as Frank said. but is not the app, is the pokemon spawning of the game. The app just brought the idea of this question as it claims is the same spot for the same pokemon. if i just asked without specifying if is my original idea would be the same question

Comment: Reopening as this is not about how a third party app works but how Pokemon Go works as discussed above.

Comment: Now it's a dupe of the one I linked, @Robotnik.

Comment: @Frank - If you think that then you should probably VTC as dupe and let the review queues decide. OP states it's about the *same* Pokemon spawning, the linked q talks about different Pokemon spawning. Thus while the answers are likely similar, I don't have enough confidence that it is a dupe to mod-close it.

Comment: @Robotnik Can't; you overrode my close vote already.

Comment: I have caught 6 dratinis at one spawn point. I work where it is so get to frequent the spot often.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, the linked question was an assumption that "yes, the same type of Pokemon always appear in the same spawn location." that's why he is asking how.. not if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Thebluefish's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/277890/119249) I will add some details.

**OVERALL, IT'S RANDOM**

The randomness of pokemon spawning around your area, are essential to give everyone a unique gaming experience. But there are some factors we could rely to expect a greater chance to catch a pokemon within an area.

**1. Rarity** Let's give the fact that there are the most common pokemons like *Rattata, Zubats, etc.*.. 
The rarity of these spawns, MIGHT BE proportion to the egg kilometer category they belong. Thus you can expect the quanity of spawns upon this, but of course it does not gauratee to be of same type.

**2. Nests** already mentioned by *Thebluefish*, nests will ensure that a particular pokemon will spawn overtime in that particular range of area, *proven by experience*, also introduced by pokemon go community, and here are some topics about pokemon nest for you to get started [Pokemon Go Nest Find](http://www.thebitbag.com/pokemon-go-rare-nests-find/164967) [Silph Road Nest Articles](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/search?q=nests&restrict_sr=on)

Notes:
1. Once Niantic have allowed live locating of pokemons, that enable developers to build apps like the famous Pokevision, which allows you to see live, where does natural spawn pokemons do spawn and when they will despawn. Be also aware that there are 2 types of pokemon spawn, *natural* and *lure*.

2. I don't have any reference but there are assuptions that certain type of pokemons will spawn based on area content, for example neardby water areas have greater possibility to spawn water type pokemons. Based on my experience, I don't find it to be always true, *but I did once caught 3 Lapras within one day on a nearby water area.*

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how much help this is but its the best i have so far:
Over a 24 hour period a dragonite spawned in the same area of a park 3 times, twice within 15 minutes. I dont know if it was a fluke and i will never see one there again or if it will be back, but if one showed up 3 times within an area of about 500 meters i would have to guess that they spawn in the same kind of area each time. If it shows up there again i will do my best to remember to update this post.

A friend also reported that a ryhorn spawns in a park near them frequently. Again, i dont know yet, i was looking for an answer to the same queation (didnt catch any of the 3 dragonites and wanted to know if/when i would have another chance) but looking at the information i have it seems like the spawns are the same and it just randomises what time they show up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on information I've read from the Silph Road (cannot find source, will edit if I do), there are **nests** where a specific type of Pokemon will spawn. O have found multiple of these nests nearby, one with 3-6 Charmane at any time, and another with 2-4 Jynx at a time.

I located these via [Pokevision](https://pokevision.com) with great success. These spots have consistently spawned their respective Pokemon over several days of monitoring.

Comment: Nests are the only gauranteed locations that a pokemon will reapeat spawing. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I caught 2 pikachus at my place of employment on different nights. I don't see them very often. I have seen 3 and 2 of them were at night at my place of employment. I don't know if this is an indicator that they will continue to spawn here or if it was just a freak thing. But, I am also curious to know if the Pokemon spawn in the same locations time after time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a park near my doctors office.

Every week I have an appointment at 2pm on Wednesdays.

Since the game went live I always see a snorlax there on my way home.

Also, the gym that is there has a snorlax at it.

For this reason I believe that it is very likely that pokemon will spawn at the same place in some sort of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Which Pokemon spawn is based on characteristics of the location (terrain, climate, etc.), so if the characteristics are right for it to spawn once, chances are it will eventually spawn again. Knowing that more than one has spawned would definitely be a stronger indicator, but even with just one, at least you know it's happened once. Consider the app as a suggestion on places to look for Pokemon you've never seen rather than an absolute guarantee that you'll find one at that location.